# Add 1 Week in DateTime to Create Expiry DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm Getting Saved Date/Time from Database in Following Format,

```
$date_time = date("j M, Y, g:i a");  //1 Feb, 2015, 12:00 am
```

Looking for a solution to add 7 days in $date_time to create expiry date, Tried several solutions discused on stackoverflow but none of them is working for me,

Any help will be appriciated. Thanks

**Edited**
@panther answered partially worked with only Date

```
    $date_time = date("j M, Y");
```

but with Date/Time

```
$date_time = date("j M, Y, g:i a");
```

adding 7 days

```
    $end_date  = date("j M, Y, g:i a", strtotime($date_time . ' + 7 days'));
```

will return the result "31 Dec, 1969, 12:00 am"
So I tried with only Date to calcualte the difference (Inside PHP While Loop)

```
        <?php if ($end_date>$date_time) { ?>
        Expired
        <?php } else { ?>
        Active
        <?php } ?>
```

And it didn't work, either it sets all records to Active or Expired,

So I'm Back to Sqaure 1.

**Note:** I tried with UNIX_TIMESTAMP but the end result same, either sets all records to Active or Expired.

Comment: `date('...', time() + 7*86400)` for the quickest/dirtiest version...

Comment: @MarcB: shehary need to work with datetime from database, not the current one.

Comment: shehary should be storing the date in native mysql format, then, not this ugly string.

Comment: @MarcB: you're right. I thought he got this date from database (and this date is different from `time()`) not that he insert it into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date_time = date("j M, Y, g:i a");
$end_date  = date("j M, Y, g:i a", strtotime($date_time . ' + 7 days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime is also a good option:

```
$date_str = "..."; // from database
$date_format = "j M, Y, g:i a";
$expire_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($date_format, $date_str);
$expire_date = $expire_date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+7 days'));
```

and if you need it formated back to string:

```
$expire_date->format($date_format);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using PHPs [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Object to get the current Time

```
$date_time_obj = new \DateTime();
$date_time = $date_time->format('j M, Y, g:i a');
```

And then use the [add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method to get your expiry time

```
$end_date_obj = clone $date_time_obj;
$end_date_obj = $end_date_obj->add(new \DateTimeInterval('P7D'));
$end_date = $end_date_obj->format('j M, Y, g:i a');
```

A little more complicated than the other answers, i know :) But maybe also a little more helpfull in the future!

Cheers